# how can i add Django Filter in one line by removing the label and making it placeholder?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-filters

this is my filters.py

```
class StudentFilterSel(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model=Student
    fields=['registrationSession','registrationNumber','studentName','applyingForClass','studentDob','studentAadharNum','fathersName','fathersContactNumber']
```

this is my views.py

```
def selectedList(request):
Studentss=Student.objects.filter(AdmissionStatus='Selected')
myFilter=StudentFilterSel(request.GET,queryset=Studentss)
Studentss=myFilter.qs
return render(request,"register/selectedList.html",{'myfilter':myFilter,"Studentss":Studentss})
```

this is my HTML file

```
<form method='get'>
{{myfilter.form}}
<button type="submit">search</button>
 </form>
```

I need a lot of filters in my table but they are getting distorted and getting in multiple lines how can I remove the label and change it to the placeholder to reduce space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise the widget, like you would in a form. The following would work on a text input field:

```
studentName = django_filters.CharFilter(label='', 
                 lookup_expr='icontains', 
                 widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Student Name'}))
```

Or you could do it in the the filter's init. The following would work for a choice field:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StudentFilterSel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.filters['registrationSession'].label = ''
    self.filters['registrationSession'].extra['empty_label'] = "Registration"
```